# C++ computing a probability for an event

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random, probability, weighted

I'm trying to simulate a Wild Pokemon encounter. As stated in the formula:

```
The rate of Pokémon encounter is determined from a simple mathematical formula:
1 in (187.5 / ( x )) per step.

Let x equal the a value which determines how rare the Pokémon is. The higher the encounter rate, 
the more common the Pokémon is.

Encounter-rate Table
Encounter type Encounter rate
Very common     10
Common          8.5
Semi-rare       6.75
Rare            3.33
Very rare       1.25
```

I want to run this probability after every press of a button. How do I simulate this with `rand()`?

Comment: Can I talk you into using [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) instead of `rand`? [`rand` kinda sucks.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: @user4581301 sure!

Comment: Sadly on re-read, `std::discrete_distribution` isn't quite the right tool for the job. It's perfect for weighting encounters, but that's not quite what you are doing here. If it was, the code would look something like: https://ideone.com/Vud9UC

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

**Mapping rand()**

```
rand() / (float)RAND_MAX
```

`Rand()` returns a value from 0 to `RAND_MAX` so this formula maps `0 -> RAND_MAX` to 
`0 -> 1`

*(float) is used to make `RAND_MAX` a float because the value returned by `rand()` is an `int` and `int / int` in c++ returns an `int`*

```
(rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 10
```

If you multiply the result by 10 it will map `rand()` from `0 -> 10`

```
(rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 187.5
```

This will map `rand()` from `0 -> 187.5`

**1 in 187.5**

We mapped the value of `rand()` from `0 -> 187.5`

Now everytime we call `rand()` it will return a random number from `0->187.5`

To simplify let's say we map `rand()` from `0 -> 200`

There will be a 1/2 chance that `rand()` will return a number lower then 100 because every number between 0 -> 200 has an equal chance of being returned (for example `rand()` can return 25.67 or 100.9 or 140.6)

```
( (rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 187.5 ) < 1
```

By the same principle there is a 1 in 187.5 chance that the number returned is smaller then 1

**Final solution**

We are still missing the 1 in 187.5 / **X**

To implement the encounter rate you just need to change the mapping from `0 -> 187.5` To

```
0 -> 187.5 / X
```

We can see that if X is big it means that there is a high encounter rate and 187.5 gets smaller and the number returned has a higher chance of being smaller then 1 but if the encounter rate is low X becomes small and 187.5 gets bigger (lower chance of being smaller then 1)

**Final code**

```
srand (time(NULL)); // Init rand() with a seed
bool encountered = ( (rand() /  (float)RAND_MAX) * (187.5 / x) ) < 1
```

**Optimisation**

A user pointed out that with the last code you need to compute 5 rand()'s for each event but if we tweak the formula a little bit you can compute only 1 `rand()`

By using simple math you know that an event that occurs once (1)  in 10 / 2 steps
is an event that occurs twice in (2) in 10 steps

So an event that occurs once (1) in 187.5 / X steps occurs (1 * X) in 187.5 steps

If we map rand() from 0 -> 187.5 Then for each pokemon we can calculate a unique value for it using only one rand()

```
float randomNumber      = (rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * 187.5
bool encountedPokemon1  = randomNumber < 1 * encounter_rate_first_pokemon
bool encountedPokemon2  = randomNumber < 1 * encounter_rate_second_pokemon
```

Comment: Good discussion and works as well as anything does with `rand` if there is only one event. There are 5 possible events. So either you are generating five numbers and give five tries at getting an encounter every step or you have to do something else.

Comment: I didn't want to add this because the user seems to be new to c++ but i will do it now that you pointed that out

Answer (score 0):

use the modulo operator. rand() will return a number between 0 and the highest value an integer can hold. so rand()%10 will return a number between 0 and 9.

(rand()%1875) <= 10 should be true 1 out of 187.5 times (or 10 out of 1875)

In case you don't already know, % will give you the remainder. So x%10 can never be greater than 9.

Here is a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)

Comment: Thanks for this but how about the other probabilities?

Comment: you would just have to put in the other numbers, the rest of the code would be the same.

Comment: Note that this also gives five tries at an encounter, one attempt per critter rarity, for every step. This might not be what's needed.

Comment: @user4581301 Good point. You could store the random number and then use separate ranges of numbers to compare the random number to.